# Merge [cloudformation] into [amazon-cloudformation]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

Seems like this tag is a duplicate of [amazon-cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudformation), so I end up adding both to my questions.

For searching and posting speed, can we merge these 2 tags?

- [cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloudformation)
- [amazon-cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudformation)

Comment: We should make [tag:cloudformation] a synonym of [tag:amazon-cloudformation].

Comment: The synonym has been suggested, [please vote if you can](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/amazon-cloudformation/synonyms).

Answer (score 1):

Done now: [cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloudformation) → [amazon-cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudformation).

As a bonus, I also merged in [aws-cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-cloudformation).

The tag wiki is…lacking because I had to reject a previously-approved version that had been shamelessly plagiarized from the official documentation. If you know something about this service, please suggest a better tag wiki.